# HTTP Status 404 - /gwtspring/com.javacodegeeks.gwtspring.Application/Application.html

Tags: spring, gwt, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have problem: HTTP Status 404 - /gwtspring/com.javacodegeeks.gwtspring.Application/Application.html I tried to write spring gwt aplication according to tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35.html. I dont know how I public client resources for example css, html, js, pictures. I have Tomcat 7.0. Cient resources are in sub directory, where tomcat blocking readning.![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your static resources in a root-folder called "res", you could do it like this. In your web.xml, add a servlet mapping BEFORE the springGwtRemoteServiceServlet mapping like

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/res/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That maps all requests to /res/* to the tomcat "default" servlet instead of passing it the the GWT servlet. Other servlet-engines have similar capabilities, but they may not call the default servlet "default".

Comment: I have still same problem http://localhost:8080/gwtspring/com.javacodegeeks.gwtspring.Application/Application.html